# Intellij IDEA shortcut How to add new element (ex. class or package)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shortcut

In Eclipse or spring tools suite, i add new class or package, for example, with shortcut CTRL+N.
Is there a corresponding shortcut in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are already in the Project View, press **Alt+Insert (New)** | Class. Project View can be activated via **Alt+1**.

Comment: If answer helpful to you , you can accept answer .It will help to find right answer to other user.